# Quickbooks API access token without oauth

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm working on a custom workflow automation for my company that includes creating expenses and invoices on Quickbooks Online. Is there anyway to avoid the oauth procedure since this is an integration only my company is gonna use?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to avoid the oauth procedure

No. Intuit uses OAuth for authentication, and that's it.